# How to start a Activity of Kotlin from Java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Can I do this below prossess in android studio?

I have a Kotlin project that I create another activity with 
its Java class and I want to start activity of Kotlin with clicking botton in activity of java then it start Kotlin activity

Comment: just do the same way you're doing with Java classes

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin is interoperable with Java. Just start the activity using an `Intent` like you would normally do in Java.

Comment: I wrote up code but show me error. my cod is  [   intent i =new intent(this, MainActivity.class);startActivity(i);  ] and show red error on startActivity(i) and compiler show to create its function!!

Comment: @irajDP Make sure that your kotlin activity has been added in the manifest, also try `File -> Invalidate Caches/ restart`, `Clean Project` & `Rebuild Project`. Also, as suggested by aaroncio, add your code to the question along with the exact error message that you get (incase the previous steps didn't fix your issue).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can start activity from java to Kotlin and vice versa.

from java

```
startActivity(new Intent(context,DestinationActivity.class))
```

from kotlin

```
startActivity(Intent(this, DestinationActivity::class.java))
```

Answer (score 0):

in java, it is

```
 startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
```

if you want to send data to the next activity in java

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, nextActivity.class);

 intent.putExtra("anyName", value);

 startActivity(intent);
```

for kotlin it is

```
startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, nextActivity::class.java)
```

if you want to send data to the next activity in kotlin

```
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Name", name)
        intent.putExtra("Email", email)
        intent.putExtra("Phone", phone)
        startActivity(intent)
```